# Strange event in Google Analytics. category: softonicmm, action: STATS_SITE_IRRELEVANT

Tags: google-analytics

When checking my Google analytics, I noticed 4 strange events. Their category is `softonicmm` and action `STATS_SITE_IRRELEVANT`.  I'm not triggering these events.

Has anyone seen similar events or have any additional information about them?

Comment: Odd...if you segment the event by hostname/page is it coming from your own site or somewhere else?

Comment: Seems to be coming from my site, as the only hostname when segmented is my own. When segmented by page, it's coming from various pages.

Comment: When segmented by Browser, all (6) are using Internet Explorer 8.0

Comment: Is this a dangerous thing? How can it be stopped?

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case it seems to have started Oct 3rd, 2012 and ended Oct 9th. It peaked on Oct 6th with a total of 5 events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a rogue internet explorer toolbar that injected javascript code into the apges the users were seeing and causing these events. Only affected internet explorer users who had that toolbar. This issue has been fixed as the company responsible for the toolbar has patched their software to avoid the events from leaking out.

Answer (score 2):

I see the `softonicmm` event for 5 days now in our Google Analytics. Maybe a new form of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam

Comment: Yes, same here.